# 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to extract the features using the get_feature_names function of the OneHotEncoder object of scikit learn but its is throwing me an error saying 
"'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'".

Below is the code snippet

```
# Creating the object instance for label encoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
onehot_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(df[data_column_category])
onehot_encoded_frame = pd.DataFrame(onehot_encoded,columns = encoder.get_feature_names(data_column_category))
```

Answer (score 12):

Apparently, it has been renamed to [`get_feature_names_out`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names_out).

Answer (score 1):

That feature was introduced recently, so you might just need to update your `sklearn` version.

You can do it as follows:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

Use get_feature_names_out instead of get_feature_names.
Look at: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: Isn't this the same as [Liz's answer](/a/74804425/4518341)? Please don't post duplicate answers. You can [submit an edit](/help/editing) if you want to improve an existing answer. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow!